# What about asking for country-specific outlets for certain subsets of movies?

Tags: discussion, scope

My wife and I love Chinese movies, but we haven't yet found a feasible way of watching them on our television that is not illegal. We're interested in paying for them legitimately. They simply don't get distributed where we live (England), or seem not to. The closest equivalent to Netflix (Lovefilm) doesn't have them.

By which I mean, of the thousands of movies that get released in China, only a select few, crappy kung fu movies get distributed here.

But given that we are in part of the EEA (European Economic Area), there may be an importer in Germany (this is just a guess) or somewhere. So would a question about Europe-wide sources for Chinese films (*on disks, not streaming*) be on topic? We've been wondering about this for years now, and I simply can't think of anywhere else to ask.

Comment: Aye, it's a bad situation, but as @Iandotkelly said, that type of question would count as too localized.  We do appreciate you asking here first.  As a side note, [I could have sworn I saw that Netflix was now available in the UK](http://www.dailymail.co.uk/sciencetech/article-2084177/Netflix-UK-launch-US-giant-takes-gamble-fierce-web-TV-battle-shapes-Amazon.html).  However, if so, [their streaming options aren't the best around.](http://www.netflix.com/BrowseSelection)

Answer (score 3):

Thank you for asking the question here first.

The scope for this site is still being formed whilst it is in beta, but from the balance of opinion so far  question like this would generally be thought of as off-topic.

If you look at the Area-51 definition for the group:

http://area51.stackexchange.com/proposals/3698?phase=definition

The question "Which sites do you consider the best ones when it comes to download popular and not so popular movies?" was closed as off-topic, and there hasn't been a groundswell of opinion since to change that.

Another reason for this being though off as off-topic, would be that it is too localized - it would only be relevant in the EU but more importantly it would probably be only correct for a certain period of time.

Comment: That said, if anyone here can point @magnetar to some resources, it can't do any harm.